# Which one is correct?

Tags: expressions

Imagine that you're going to sell a package containing eight scrubber brushes. For advertising the product the number of items should be displayed on the first line and item type on the second line. Which one is correct? I used '/' for separating two phrases:

1- Eight-piece/scrubber brushes

2- Eight piece/scrubber brushes

3- Eight pieces/scrubber brushes

4- Eight pieces/scrubber brush

UPDATE: I'm sorry for my inadequate explanation of this issue. I want to put a text inside the image of my product on Amazon. This text will break in three lines: a) Brand name b) 8 Piece(s) c) Scrubber Brush(es). I don't want to use 'of' because no one does this on Amazon.

Comment: None of these, if you ask me. For advertising the product, the product must be named first and not last. Are you selling brushes, or are you selling pieces? The 1 in particular sounds funny because you're saying each brush consists of eight pieces. If you absolutely need to state the quantity first, just drop the *pieces* and say "eight scrubber brushes".

Comment: The normal way this would be shown on a site like Amazon.com is to name the product "Scrubber brushes", and then in the description say "Package of 8". You could combine it as "Scrubber brushes (package of 8)".

Comment: We don't use 'pieces' in this sense in English, to refer to multiple items in a pack. And in my (British) English I would call them 'scrubbing brushes'.

Comment: I'm sorry for my inadequate explanation of this issue. I want to put a text inside the image of my product on Amazon. This text will break in three lines: a) Brand name b) 8 Piece(s) c) Scrubber Brush(es). I don't want to use 'of' because no one does this on Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

If selling to England I think you should use "Scrubbing" rather than "Scrubber".  'Scrubber' has a rather unfortunate connotation; it refers to an amateur 'lady of easy virtue', or a lady known to have a number of 'gentlemen friends'...

"8 Scrubbing Brushes" would work.

"8-piece" would imply you need to join them together to make them work.

"8-pieces" is usually used (Like "8-off") in engineering to define the number of a particular thing that are required - its not usually used in "Sales & Marketing".

Answer (score -1):

If it is in formal english, it use "eight pieces ***of*** scrubber brushes". For advertising, it often use numeral value "Package of 8" or "Package of eight pieces" on "eight pieces" on the first line and "Scrubber brush"(not plural) to describe the item that are selling.

Comment: I've seen phrases like _huit pièces_ on French packaging, but _piece_ isn't  used with that sense in English.